# Strange formatting on wordpress blog post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried changing the blog page to display whole posts instead of excerpts by changing `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` to `<?php the_content(); ?>`. I made this change on the index.php file and the page-blog.php file.

Looked good until I scrolled down to the third post called "Chalk it Up". The bar that should be at the very bottom of the post with the author, date, and comment info is instead just below the video right in the middle of the post. The title for the next post is right there as well.

This is the code for the bar that is in the wrong place:

```
<footer class="entry-meta">
<?php theretailer_posted_on(); ?>
<?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
<span class="sep"> | </span>
<span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'theretailer' ), __( '1 Comment', 'theretailer' ), __( '% Comments', 'theretailer' ) ); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'theretailer' ), '<span class="sep"> | </span><span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix it?

http://glitterriot.com/blog/

Comment: More code where you list the post is needed.

Comment: I just updated the description. let me know if I should put more in.

Comment: redreggae's answer fixes it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because of the floating. try to add a div with `clear:both` right before the footer.

```
/* in css */
.clear {
    clear: both;
    height: 0px;
}


<div class="clear"></div>
<footer class="entry-meta">
....
```

Comment: Added it to the index.php file and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!